# C pointer addresses and casting

Tags: c

I feel like I have a good understanding of pointers, but I want to make sure I am understanding this correctly.

Basically, I am completing a computer architecture lab for virtual memory and we have 2 pointers. One pointer represents main memory, and other represents an array of structs (`frame_table`) that starts at `mem[0]`.

When I am initializing the program, I need to set `&frame_table[0] = &mem[0]` (I know the `&` and `[]` are redundant).

My question is, when doing this, do I need to cast the address of `mem`? Based on my understanding, I would say no. The way I think about it is I am setting the address of `frame_table` to the address of `mem`, which is not dependent on types at all. I have my example below.

In addition, if there are any similar cases where I would need to cast, or casting would produce undefined behavior, please let me know.

```
uint8_t *mem;
fte_t *frame_table;

//do i do this?
frame_table = mem;

//or this?
frame_table = (fte_t*) mem;
```

Comment: Think of "casting" as removing the usual guardrails that the compiler uses to warn of dubious operations. "Casting", is the coder telling the compiler, "keep quiet, I know what I am doing here."

Comment: Relevant: [What is the strict aliasing rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both C and C++, pointers of *unrelated* types are NOT implicitly convertible to each other (however, in C but not C++, converting from a `void*` pointer to any other pointer type is allowed implicitly).

In this example, since `fte_t` is a different type than `uint8_t`, a type-cast is required.

Comment: In C, conversion involving `void*` is allowed in either direction without explicit casting, no?

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was thinking too much about what a pointer represents(an address) and forgot they also have types along with the things they reference

Comment: @Fe2O3 both C and C++ allow implicit conversion TO `void*`, but only C allows implicit conversion FROM `void*`, yes. C++ requires explicit casting FROM `void*`

Answer (score -1):

You can assign and cast, but you can't use this pointer without invoking undefined behaviour (UB).

To pun the types I would rather recommend memcpy or unions